# How to display data below my form in drupal 7 custom module

Tags: forms, drupal, module

I have custom module built, form displays and validation and submit works fine.
My thinking is to retrieve the data from database which are saved from my form and display them back underneath my custom form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use #sufix (and #prefix if you need it) parameter:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/5#prefix

Comment: Wow. that does the trick, I add among my form array and it works like a charm!!